# Software or libraries to create doc-term matrix

Tags: references, natural-language, text-mining, java

Does anyone know some ***Java libraries*** to create the document-term matrix for a large number (50,000) of documents? I wish this library encompasses preprocessing functionalities, like stop-word and punctuation removal, stemming, etc. What's more, I wish to use TF*IDF weighting scheme, and normalization functionality. Preferably, I prefer Java libraries for the convenience of development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) offers this functionality in Java. Start Weka and open the `Explorer`. Then load your dataset and apply the `StringToWordVector` filter. This filter can create a doc term matrix (either binary or by frequency), do IDF, stopword removal, stemming, normalization, punctuation removal and more.

Comment: After my experiment, I think **Weka** will be suitable for not very huge sizes (several hundred MB txt data). Otherwise, weka will throw a "java heap size" problem, because it stores all texts for preprocessing and their statistics in RAM. For more code, perhaps, interested readers may refer to [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA) Last but not least, Weka is the best for documentation among all proposed solutions! Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that it suits your needs. About the heap size problem; You can set the heap size of Java to a higher value when you run Weka (see http://weka.wikispaces.com/OutOfMemoryException).

Comment: :-) of course i know how to increase the Java Heap size, but  Weka's strategy to hold all files and their info in RAM is not feasible when I use 100K files to preprocess. What's worse, my file are more than 10K words per file. So I am afraid i have to figure another "intelligent" and tricky method to handle this :-). Anyway, thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 3):

[JFreq](http://williamlowe.net/software/jfreq/) might do what you want.  There's a command line version too.

Comment: Hum, it seems that this software meeting my requirements perfectly. I will look into it, and hopefully, I can plug it as a module in my application.

Comment: I am afraid this tool is not suitable for redevelopment (integrate in your own software), and also, lack of documentation for development work :-(

Comment: It's true that it's more an application rather than a library. You probably want something like [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) then.

Answer (score 2):

I would vote for [http://lucene.apache.org/](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and http://mahout.apache.org/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems lucene is a toolkit for search engine, while mahout includes some implementations for large-scale machine learning algorithms. I found both of them lack sufficient documentations, and also examples. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Cleartk http://code.google.com/p/cleartk/ is a package built on top of Apache UIMA.  Configuration is a bit tricky, but it works.